# How can I remove DRM from an audible audiobook (aax)?

Tags: mp3, convert, audible

I hope I do not ask anything that is illegal. I have purchased an audiobook and audible offers to download the corresponding file, which is an aax file. As far as I understood one can somehow extract the authentication code, convert the file and use it as mp3. But all I found were solutions which used someone's code (projekt "tables") from github. I did not find anything in the apt repositories from Ubuntu and do not know if I should trust that source. Therefore I need a way to get it work without any third party software that I don't know and where I do not believe that other people have checked the code.

Is there a safe procedure that you can recommend?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: I disagree, because I use Ubuntu and therefore I do not seek a solution for windows (as there is many software for that case out there).

Comment: keep in mind DRM is an antipiracy measure - removing DRM could violate the law in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Yes, I am not quite sure. I just read on another site that this would be okay. I am not sure. After all I purchased the file and just want to use it with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

#### AAXtoMP3

The purpose of this software is to convert AAX (or AAXC) files to common MP3, M4A, M4B, flac and ogg formats through a basic bash script front-end to FFMPEG.

AAXtoMP3 is a bash shell script that can be run as a normal user without `sudo`

1. Download the zip archive from https://github.com/KrumpetPirate/AAXtoMP3/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
2. Extract the contents of AAXtoMP3-master.zip.
3. Install dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt install ffmpeg lame jq mediainfo
   ```
4. Change directories with `cd` to the directory that contains AAXtoMP3 and run  `bash AAXtoMP3` to display its command-line options or run either of the two usage commands.

   Usage:

   ```
   bash AAXtoMP3 [-f|--flac] [-o|--opus] [-a|-aac] [-s|--single] [--level <COMPRESSIONLEVEL>] [-c|--chaptered] [-e:mp3] [-e:m4a] [-e:m4b] [-A|--authcode <AUTHCODE>] [-n|--no-clobber] [-t|--target_dir <PATH>] [-C|--complete_dir <PATH>] [-V|--validate] [--use-audible-cli-data]] [-d|--debug] [-h|--help] [--continue <CHAPTERNUMBER>] <AAX/AAXC INPUT_FILES>...
   ```

   or if you want to get guided through the options:

   ```
   bash interactiveAAXtoMP3 [-a|--advanced] [-h|--help]
   ```

Comment: Thank you, but as mentioned before I am a little sceptical to use any third party software which is not part of the dist repositories. Is there a way to use out of the box software of Ubuntu?

Comment: @MDoe I love Linux and use Ubuntu every day. AAXtoMP3 runs right out of the box from your home directory without any requirement to install it except for installing its dependencies (in step 3 of my answer) which are all available in the default Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Okay, I am not that experienced. I was just afraid that some code could compromise my computer or so.

Answer (score 0):

I used ViWizard [Audible Converter](https://www.viwizard.com/audible-converter/) which can convert my Audible books to MP3 and simultaneously remove DRM from Audible. Hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To remove DRM from an Audible AAX audiobook, you can use various tools and methods.
Here are some options:

- Audible Manager
- AudKit Audible Converter
- inAudible
- iTunes